# $f: G \to \mathbb{C}^*$ is a homomorphism. Show that the sum $\sum f (g) = 0$ or $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

Let $ \mathbb{C}^*$ be the multiplicative group of non-zero complex numbers. Let $G$ be an abelian group and suppose $f: G \to \mathbb{C}^*$ is a homomorphism. Prove that $\sum_{g \in G} f(g)=n$ or, $\sum_{g \in G} f(g)=0$, where $n  =o(G)$

Proof attempt:

The case is evident for the trivial homomorphism; the sum adds up to $n$.

*For the second part*

We know, the only elements with finite order in the group $ \mathbb{C}^*$ are $1$ and $-1$, with $o(-1)=2$.

Now, the only case when $f(g)$ can take $-1$ as a value is when $n$ is even.

Consider the subgroup $(\{1, -1\}, .) = G'$  of the group $ \mathbb{C}^*$. We have, from the Isomorphism Theorem, $ G/ \ker( f ) \simeq G' $ [since $f$ takes each value from $G'$].

As $o(G')=2$, $o(G/ \ker( f ))=2$, i.e $o(\ker (f))= n/2$. Hence, when summed, the resultant is $0$.

Edit: A foolish assumption has been taken. The finite ordered complex numbers in the said group is of the form $z^n=1$, so I have 'proved' a very restricted case, which is not at all desired.

Comment: What's the order of $i$ then?

Comment: Does G have to have finite order?

Comment: @JoelPereira:. isn't that implied by the statements $\sum f(g) = n$  and $n = o(G)$?

Comment: @the_fox :( back to square one.

Comment: @RobertLewis no it's not implied. If G = the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{R}^+$, we can still form the sum. In that case the sum would diverge.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not necessary that $G$ be abelian, to wit:

If

$f(g) = 1, \; \forall g \in G, \tag 1$

then clearly

$\displaystyle \sum_{g \in G} f(g) = n, \tag 2$

since

$o(G) = n; \tag 3$

if

$\exists h \in G, \; f(h) \ne 1, \tag 4$

then since

$hG = G, \tag 5$

we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{g \in G} f(g) &= \sum_{g \in G} f(hg) \\
&= \sum_{g \in G} f(h)f(g) \\
&= f(h)\sum_{g \in G} f(g); \tag 6
\end{align}$$

with $f(h) \ne 1$ this forces

$\displaystyle \sum_{g \in G} f(g) = 0. \tag 7$

$OE\Delta$.

Comment: @Shaun:  nice edit, thanks!

Comment: Amazing. Just amazing.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if they just assumed abelian so that students could use the fundamental theorem. It's very easy to prove for cyclic groups.

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas:  thank you for your kind words.  If you really like my answer, you might consider "accepting" it.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one novel way using representation theory. The homomorphism $f$ is a (1-dimensional) irreducible representation of a finite group $G$ and $\sum_{g \in G} f(g)$ is the sum of the character $\chi_f$ over $g \in G$, i.e. $\chi_f = f$.

Since $\sum_{g \in G} \chi_f(g) = \lvert G \rvert\langle \chi_f, 1 \rangle$, the sum is zero if and only if $1$ is not a direct summand of $f$. In that case, $f$ is trivial and the sum is $n$.

Comment: Can you please verify mine?

Comment: the_fox in one of the earlier comments has already pointed out that a mistake in your proof is assuming the only elements with finite order in $\mathbb{C}^*$ are $\pm 1$, when in fact any complex $z$ such that $z^\ell = 1$ for a nonzero integer $\ell$, i.e. a root of unity, has finite order at most $\ell$.

Comment: $z^n=1$ does form a group. Now, can we somehow follow my approach to prove it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can adapt your approach. I might give this a go later myself, but you might be able to adapt it by first using the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups to first decompose $G$ into finite cyclic groups $\mathbb{Z}_{m}$. On the direct summand $\mathbb{Z}_{m}$, if $g_i$ is a generator, so that $g_i^m = 1$, then if we let $z = f(g_i)$ then $z^m = 1$ and $1 + z + \cdots + z^{m-1} = 0$ if $z \neq 1$.

Comment: I was thinking exactly along this line. Now, conversion of this into isomorphism theorem would be really nice. :)